# Spring Boot webapp - unexpected shutdown of ExecutorService

Tags: spring-boot

I have a vanilla Spring Boot web application, with some controllers, REST services etc. There is no notion of thread pools, shutdown hooks etc. in the webapp's sources. The app itself does not use any other services, like external databases.

The app worked well until it started to die within two or three days on average after being started. In the logs everything looks normal until this lonely message:

`--- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'`

that has the last timestamp, even if shown in the logs a bit out of chronological order. The message is preceded by this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol [HTTP/1.10x0aHost:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:559) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

which in turn has no time stamp, so it is difficult to say how these two are related or if they are related at all.

After that, the app no longer responds to requests. Where can I look for causes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log fragment you have quoted is not a cause but it is an effect of application beeing gracefully shut down

```
--- [extShutdownHook]
```

says this is a hook set on a JVM exit routine. So when, for example, you send a kill singal to the JVM, hooks set via setShutdownHook() will be called - and this is exactly what you see - thread pool is shutdown because JVM is requested to be terminated.

Now, I cannot state why it is terminated, but it is possible that you run out of resoureces (for whatever reasons) and OS (linux?) is killing the most resource consuming process.  It is also possible that OS is killing long running processes due to some settings (happenned to me in the past that hoster was killing long runing process)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `scope` as `provided` for **tomcat** dependency in **pom.xml**. Try removing that.
It might be the reason of graceful shutdown of tomcat when it finds ideal threads.

```
--- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
```

Comment: Could you give some detail? I cannot find anything about ideal threads. I use scope as compiled for both `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and `tomcat-embed-jasper`.

Comment: if you are using ```spring-boot-starter-web``` , i would recommend to remove the tomcat dependencies explicitly specified . If you are not using web starter, i would say , add ```spring-boot-starter-web``` to your pom and remove tomcat dependencies.

Comment: I guess that jasper is not included in the starter,